# Grails - findAll Posts Created Today by User

Tags: hibernate, grails, date, grails-orm

I have a domain object.

```
class Post {
  User user
  String subject
  String body
  Date dateCreated
}
```

How do I go about this? Is straight GORM, HQL, or criteria the better way?
I didn't know what kind of date manipulation ("today eq") would work in criteria.

Answer (score 11):

I would probably make a named query

```
class Post {
  User user
  String subject
  String body
  Date dateCreated

     static namedQueries = {
       todaysPosts {
          def now = new Date().clearTime()
          between('dateCreated', now, now+1)
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Post.todaysPosts.count()
```

or

```
Post.todaysPosts.list()
Post.todaysPosts.list(max: 10, offset: 5)
```

you can even do

```
Post.todaysPosts.findAllByUser(user)
```

[Here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) is more on named queries

Comment: Although it looks really nice, namedQueries are deprecated in Grails 4.x. Use where queries instead.

Comment: Agreed. This was answered in 2011 and was valid then.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a criteria example:

```
// assuming future posts are disallowed
def posts = Post.withCriteria {
    eq('user', user)
    ge('dateCreated', new Date().clearTime())
}

// if you must accommodate future posts
def today = new Date().clearTime()
def posts = Post.withCriteria {
    eq('user', user)
    ge('dateCreated', today)
    lt('dateCreated', today.plus(1))
}
```

Comment: If `today <= dateCreated < today + 1`... doesn't that include all dates?

Answer (score 3):

I would use Grails Dynamic Finders to accomplish this:

```
Post.findAllByUserAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals(currentUser, new Date().clearTime())
```

Where "currentUser" is an instance of the current user

Comment: Forgot about the "AndUserEquals" since they only want the current user's stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Post p WHERE p.dateCreated  = NOW()"
def e = Post.executeQuery(sqlQuery)
```

Comment: This is rather DB-specific, no?   NOW(), or SYSDATE, or whatever it is for the DB they're using.

Comment: This is certainly _a_ solution, but it does not use Hibernate or GORM.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is a query written in HQL:

```
def yourUser = User.get(1)
def results = Post.executeQuery( "select * from Post a where a.user = :user and a.dateCreated >= :dateCreated", [user : yourUser , dateCreated : new Date().clearTime()] );
```

@Tyndall: there are many answers for this question, just take one that you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @sbglasius: it depend. You can always format your query string into many lines to make it easier to read