# Grails - dynamic finders derived date query GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following domain class

```
class Book {
    String title
    Date releaseDate
    Integer daysOnShelf
    Author author
}
```

How can I list all books where current date is greater than the `releaseDate` + `daysOnShelf`? For instance, don't list if `2015-02-10 + 5` (`releaseDate + daysOnShelf`) since date is less than now.

Can this be done using GORM dynamic finders or Criteria Builder ? e.g.,

```
 def index(Integer max) {
     def books = Book.findAll {
         releaseDate.plus(daysOnShelf) < new Date()
     }
     respond books
 }
```

Comment: It does not. throws an exception: `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.plus() is applicable for argument types... Possible solutions: list(), sum()...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456061/grails-findall-posts-created-today-by-user

Comment: close, however, I'm looking to add days to the class property `releaseDate` instead of current date (as in the link)?. e.g., `gt ('releaseDate' - daysOnShelf), now`

Comment: Why not just add the days on to now? because maths ;-)

Comment: You may have to use hql do any complex date functions.  Not sure you can do that with gorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should acchieve what you want:

```
Date dateMinusDaysOnShelf = new Date() - daysOnShelf

Book.findAllByReleaseDateLessThan(dateMinusDaysOnShelf)
```